# Bootstrap Tagsinput and TypeAhead default object for freeInput

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead, typeahead.js

I'm using Bootstrap TagsInput from https://github.com/TimSchlechter/bootstrap-tagsinput

My code reads as

```
$("#example > input").tagsinput({
    itemValue: function (item) {                
        return item.value;
    },
    itemText: function (item) {                
        return item.text;
    },         
    typeahead: {
        source: [
            { "value": 1, "text": "Amsterdam" },
            { "value": 2, "text": "Bmsterdam" },
            { "value": 3, "text": "Cmsterdam" },
            { "value": 4, "text": "Dmsterdam"}
        ],
        freeInput: true
    }
});
```

Everything works well except the freeInput, it can't seems to create a default value & text paid object. How do i allow the freeInput?

Answer (score 1):

From http://timschlechter.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/ under freeInput option:

> "Allow creating tags which are not returned by typeahead's source (default: true)
>
> This is only possible when using string as tags. When itemValue option is set, this option will be ignored."

Answer (score 0):

Freeinput is true by default when using typeahead. "Source" property is also depreciated as far as I know when using typeahead Bootstrap 3 and Twitter's typeahead. So be advised of that gotcha as well. Typically in most cases freeInput would likely need to be false if using a remote source. Probably don't want free input this as you'll want to constrain to items in the list.

Again though the first thing I'd look into if using the latest ver. of Typeahead and Bootstrap is the source property. You probably want "prefetch" for a remote source and "local" for a simple array or array of objects.